# inconsistent results while reading file in binary c++. READ BODY

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

As shown in the picture, if I read 2 bytes at offset 254786 and print it in hexadecimal, I should be getting 0xffd9 and I do get that exact value if I directly set the offset to 254786. however, if I set the offset to something far away from 254786 and run a while loop as shown in the second picture, I do not get 0xffd9. I really don't know where I could be possibly going wrong here.

```
std::ifstream myfile ("test-01.jpg");

    if(!myfile) throw std::runtime_error("unable to open input file");
    
    
    myfile.seekg(254786,myfile.beg);
    std::string buf {};
    buf.resize(2);
    myfile.read(&buf[0], 2);
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << big_endian_2_bytes_to_int(buf);
```

```
0xffd9
```

```
int offset = 17000  
 std::cout << offset << std::endl;
                myfile.seekg(offset,myfile.beg);
                myfile.read(&buffer[0],2);
            while (  big_endian_2_bytes_to_int(buffer) != 0xffd9){
                offset++;
                myfile.seekg(offset,myfile.beg);
                myfile.read(&buffer[0],2);
                if (offset == 254786){
                    std::cout << offset <<std::endl;
                    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << big_endian_2_bytes_to_int(buffer) << std::endl;
                    return 0;
                }

            }
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Reading into the address of a character in an empty `std::string` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're opening the file in text mode. That's not a good idea, in particular on Windows.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't even notice that, thank you so much